# Is it legal to imitate how an API looks?

Tags: api, legal, copyright

I want to make an open-source graph thing which looks and behaves very similarly to Google Visualization API, but it would be based on Flot. Is this legal, or must I not imitate Google Visualization API?

Comment: Google would likely be the least likely company to argue that copying an API is illegal.

Comment: Didn't google just battle over this very thing with Oracle?

Comment: The answer to this question is going to be super-locality specific.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about local legal issues, not software development.

Comment: I believe this is on-topic as it is clearly a factor that must be considered in API design. A good answer could easily outline the general legal issues without going into the specifics of every jurisdiction.

Comment: @mikera - You expect an answer to outline the legal issues of every jurisdiction that would be a very broad answer and considering we are not lawyers would likely be incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GNU has a long history of making work alikes for libraries.  When BSD was sued for copyright it was over implementation copying and not interface copying (reimplementing the Unix interface was considered a valid resolution). Then as whatsisname points out in the comments Oracle lost when they sued Google for API copyright. Work alikes have a long history of being legal.  So it should be ok.  Though as always I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice.

Comment: According to [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/82461/93286) answer it should be legal.